# What is the Unicode of the Arrow Keys in java

Tags: java, unicode, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to code a web browser in minecraft and I'm having trouble with the arrow keys. What is each one in Unicode. I already have this btw. Yes the browser is working and I have gotten mouse input and every other key done. I have included the type() method, key() method, and getChar() method. All it does in get the char and send it to the type() method so the web browser knows how to type it in.

```
public void type(BlockSide side, String text, BlockPos soundPos) {
        Screen scr = getScreen(side);
        if(scr == null) {
            Log.error("Tried to type on invalid screen on side %s", side.toString());
            return;
        }

        if(level.isClientSide) {
            if(scr.browser != null) {
                try {
                    if(text.startsWith("t")) {
                        for(int i = 1; i < text.length(); i++) {
                            char chr = text.charAt(i);
                            if(chr == 1)
                                break;

                            scr.browser.injectKeyTyped(chr, 0);
                        }
                    } else {
                        TypeData[] data = WebDisplays.GSON.fromJson(text, TypeData[].class);

                        for(TypeData ev : data) {
                            switch (ev.getAction()) {
                                case PRESS -> scr.browser.injectKeyPressedByKeyCode(ev.getKeyCode(), (char) ev.getKeyCode(), 0);
                                case RELEASE -> scr.browser.injectKeyReleasedByKeyCode(ev.getKeyCode(), (char) ev.getKeyCode(), 0);
                                case TYPE -> {
                                    if(ev.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                                        scr.browser.injectKeyTyped(, 0);
                                    }
                                    scr.browser.injectKeyTyped(ev.getKeyCode(), 0);
                                }
                                default -> throw new RuntimeException("Invalid type action '" + ev.getAction() + '\'');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch(Throwable t) {
                    Log.warningEx("Suspicious keyboard type packet received...", t);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Messages.INSTANCE.send(PacketDistributor.NEAR.with(() -> point(level, getBlockPos())), CMessageScreenUpdate.type(this, side, text));

            if(soundPos != null)
                playSoundAt( WebDisplays.INSTANCE.soundTyping, soundPos, 0.25f, 1.f);
        }
    }
```

```
  @Override
    public boolean keyPressed(int keyCode, int scanCode, int modifiers) {
        key(keyCode, scanCode, true, modifiers);
        return super.keyPressed(keyCode, scanCode, modifiers);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyReleased(int keyCode, int scanCode, int modifiers) {
        key(keyCode, scanCode, false, modifiers);
        return super.keyPressed(keyCode, scanCode, modifiers);
    }

    public void key(int keyCode, int scanCode, boolean pressed, int mod) {
        if (pressed) {
            if(quitOnEscape && keyCode == GLFW.GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) {
                Minecraft.getInstance().setScreen(null);
            }

            int chr = getChar(keyCode, scanCode);
            evStack.add(new TypeData(TypeData.Action.PRESS, chr, mod));
            evStack.add(new TypeData(TypeData.Action.RELEASE, chr, mod));

            if (keyCode != 0)
                evStack.add(new TypeData(TypeData.Action.TYPE, chr, mod));

            if (!evStack.isEmpty() && !syncRequested())
                requestSync();
        }
    }
```

```
    public int getChar(int keyCode, int scanCode) {
        String keystr = GLFW.glfwGetKeyName(keyCode, scanCode);
        if(keystr == null){
            keystr = "\0";
        }
        if(keyCode == GLFW.GLFW_KEY_ENTER){
            return 13;
        }
        if (keyCode == GLFW.GLFW_KEY_SPACE) {
            return 32;
        }
        if(keystr.length() == 0){
            return -1;
        }
        if(hasShiftDown()) {
            keystr = keystr.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT);
            return CefBrowserOsr.remapKeycode(keyCode, keystr.charAt(keystr.length() - 1));
        } else {
            return CefBrowserOsr.remapKeycode(keyCode, keystr.charAt(keystr.length() - 1));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not every key on a keyboard corresponds to a Unicode character. You wrote the rest of your code wrong if it relies on the assumption that they do. Please include more of it in your question so we can show you exactly where your mistake is.

Comment: it seems like you need the **scan code** for the arrow keys, similar as done with `GLFW_KEY_ENTER` and `GLFW_KEY_SPACE`... maybe GLFW [Keyboard keys](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__keys.html) can help. **||** ( for Unicode I use [decodeunicode](https://decodeunicode.org/) or [unicode.org](https://unicode.org/)  but I do not think that Unicode will help in this case - see Joseph's comment )